# How to select all childnodes when a parent node is selected in treeview ? (When the treeview is used from usercontrol)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a usercontrol which has only the Treeview control.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="Tree_Index" 
Style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" runat="server" Width="10px" 
EnableClientScript="False" ShowCheckBoxes="All" ShowLines="True">
</asp:TreeView>
```

From my aspx page i use this user control multiple times, inorder to show multiple treeview with different data in my aspx page.

I call the user control like below

```
Public Sub PopulateTreeview() 
        Dim cph As ContentPlaceHolder = CType(Me.Master.FindControl("cphMain"), ContentPlaceHolder)
    Dim Treeview_Control As Controls_Deot_treecontrol

        Dim ds As DataSet = SPServiceModel.GetAllServiceCategorizationTypes()
        Dim dtRight As DataTable = ds.Tables(0) 

        For i As Integer = 0 To dtRight.Rows.Count - 1
        Treeview_Control = CType(LoadControl("Deot/treecontrol.ascx"), Controls_Deot_treecontrol)
        Treeview_Control.ID = "Treecontrol_Right_" + i.ToString()
        Treeview_Control.SetCategoryID(dtRight.Rows(i)("id").ToString())
            cph.FindControl("pnl_right").Controls.Add(Treeview_Control)
        Next 
End Sub
```

Say if there are 6 treeviews are there on my aspx page. I want to select all the child nodes of a parent node when a parent node is selected. The treeview will have three levels of node . So all the nodes inside the parent node should be selected for that particular tree.

How can i achieve this, because the ID is set by me in aspx page. How can i achieve this using javascript or jquery or codebehind of user control ?

Rendered HTML :

```
<div id="ctl00_cphMain_pnl_left">



     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div[id $= Tree_Index] input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
                $(this).closest("table").next("div").find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", this.checked);
            });
        });
    </script>


<a href="#ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_SkipLink"><img width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" src="/WebResource.axd?d=vp_dPIRRqCpyFrxPBwqvPmsO-wa56CpxZGlT_T-AdX5QN0qJOs_wgfq4QMJwRILSj9XSONYmkJAe85CVEph0Q1SfUqs1&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt="Skip Navigation Links."></a><div style="width:10px;font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" onclick="OnTreeClick(event)" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','t1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c')"><img style="border-width:0;" alt="Collapse Clinics" src="/WebResource.axd?d=_533LbcrYzxclETTqT9E9lbjpoP9iiSVLn9WP908dD96sH9D2JXH4BN8Q2OdATM4TYJU67kfDSnJQpffp_ITMVu3Y839pir-IzEhB41mqu6U8EWb0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0">Clinics</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\8086a7e5-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0">Respite Care Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\5586a7e5-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0">Caregiver Training</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\643eafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0">Psychiatric Rehabilitation Homes</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext4" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\613dafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0">Befriending Service</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\6fe899f7-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0">Polyclinics</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn6CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn6CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext6" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\7393b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0">Caregiver Support Service</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext7" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\7a93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0">Helpline - Caregiver Helpline</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_SkipLink"></a>
<br>



     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div[id $= Tree_Index] input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
                $(this).closest("table").next("div").find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", this.checked);
            });
        });
    </script>


<a href="#ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_SkipLink"><img width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" src="/WebResource.axd?d=vp_dPIRRqCpyFrxPBwqvPmsO-wa56CpxZGlT_T-AdX5QN0qJOs_wgfq4QMJwRILSj9XSONYmkJAe85CVEph0Q1SfUqs1&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt="Skip Navigation Links."></a><div style="width:10px;font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" onclick="OnTreeClick(event)" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','tace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7')"><img style="border-width:0;" alt="Collapse Home Care" src="/WebResource.axd?d=_533LbcrYzxclETTqT9E9lbjpoP9iiSVLn9WP908dD96sH9D2JXH4BN8Q2OdATM4TYJU67kfDSnJQpffp_ITMVu3Y839pir-IzEhB41mqu6U8EWb0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Home Care</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','tace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\0f93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')"><img style="border-width:0;" alt="Collapse Home Nursing" src="/WebResource.axd?d=PtoZaOE4OJ68kA17eB1Ru-nLDbZ-ilvB8z5abVJ8BfKZp0iKKZ8iPpsV8tJ5bLWmNAAyfP3gCpxQRyrUtuHqeJKGILYd8Nbb3deoYK17HD9ZYyeS0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\0f93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Home Nursing</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\0f93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039\\00000000-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Third Level 1</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\0f93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039\\11111111-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Third Level 2</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext4" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\c13eafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Private Nursing Homes</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\1493a4eb-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Personal Healthcare Assistant</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn6CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn6CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext6" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\f592b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Home Medical</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext7" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\2493b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Home Therapy - Physiotherapy</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn8CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn8CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext8" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\1a93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Home Therapy - Occupational Therapy</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn9CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn9CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext9" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\083eafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Social Day Care Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn10CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn10CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext10" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\e7ba9bfd-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Community VWO Clinics</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn11CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn11CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext11" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\b292b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Day Rehabilitation Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn12CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn12CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext12" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\2087a7e5-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Community Wellness Clubs</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn13CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn13CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext13" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\8f93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0">Community Hospitals</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_SkipLink"></a>
<br>



     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div[id $= Tree_Index] input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
                $(this).closest("table").next("div").find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", this.checked);
            });
        });
    </script>


<a href="#ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_SkipLink"><img width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" src="/WebResource.axd?d=vp_dPIRRqCpyFrxPBwqvPmsO-wa56CpxZGlT_T-AdX5QN0qJOs_wgfq4QMJwRILSj9XSONYmkJAe85CVEph0Q1SfUqs1&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt="Skip Navigation Links."></a><div style="width:10px;font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" onclick="OnTreeClick(event)" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','tfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f')"><img style="border-width:0;" alt="Collapse Other Services" src="/WebResource.axd?d=_533LbcrYzxclETTqT9E9lbjpoP9iiSVLn9WP908dD96sH9D2JXH4BN8Q2OdATM4TYJU67kfDSnJQpffp_ITMVu3Y839pir-IzEhB41mqu6U8EWb0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0">Other Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\45bb0a98-ec44-e211-beaf-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0">Mobile Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\9b3dafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0">Hospice Day Care</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\f83dafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0">Website - Disability Information Website</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext4" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\33333333-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0">Information &amp; Referral Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox"><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\44444444-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0">Ambulance Service (Non-Emergency)</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_SkipLink"></a>
<br>


</div>
```

Comment: If you want solution in jquery then instead of posting code of aspx page , you should post the rendered HTML . and no need to post code of vb.net.

Comment: @rahularyansharma I have updated the question with HTML that is rendered. The HTML will have 3 treeview controls

Comment: I have tried to put your HTML in jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/s3Bz4/ you can change it to look better  and post its link also in your question .

Comment: @rahularyansharma Look better in the sense ? I just copied the HTML rendered from my browser. Thanks.

Comment: @rahularyansharma On clicking Clinics (Parent) select all the child nodes of it. On clicking Home care (Parent) select all the child nodes of it. On clicking Other Services (Parent) select all the child nodes of it.

Comment: yes i got it and doing this for you . give me some time please .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30458/discussion-between-rahularyansharma-and-anuya)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div[id $= Tree_Index]").find("input[type=checkbox]:first").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("div").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

[js fiddle link is here](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/s3Bz4/6/)